# Enable shipping address for specific virtual products from a product category in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I have a category gate for showing shipping on virtual products. Basically I have products I dont want to charge shipping on and I have them in a category called gifts... but I still want a shipping address. The problem is, is that when I use the category filter I built it wont save the address in the order... if i just use...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true', 50 );
```

It works great...

But when i put the gate on it... it wont save the values... here is the gate...

```
//gifts filter
function HDM_gift_shipping() {
// set our flag to be false until we find a product in that category
$cat_check = false;

// check each cart item for our category
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

   // if cat matches gift return true
    if ( has_term( 'gift', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
        $cat_check = true;
        // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
        break;
    }
}

// if a product in the cart is in our category, do something
if ( $cat_check ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true', 50 );
}

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'HDM_gift_shipping', 100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code. To get that working, you should better set your code directly in the `woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'custom_cart_needs_shipping_address', 50, 1 );
function custom_cart_needs_shipping_address( $needs_shipping_address ) {
    // Loop though cat items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( array('gift'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            // Force enable shipping address for virtual "gift" products
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping_address;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **In cart**, to handle Woocommerce **custom taxonomies** like product categories or tags when using **`has_term()`** WordPress conditional function, you need to use **`$cart_item['product_id']`** instead of `$cart_item['data']->get_id()` that doesn't work for product variations.

Comment: Once again coming in clutch with that answer. Sounds like you know your stuff!

Comment: One last question, say I wanted to limit it to a Tag rather than a Category. Would I just reaplace 'product_cat' with 'product_tag' ?

Comment: @MattNath replace the taxonomy 'product_cat' by 'product_tag' in the code.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you again!